# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection] with root cause java.sql.SQLException:

Tags: spring, hibernate

Hello I m still new with spring and hibernate it s my first app tryin to get connected to db but I  m getting this excepton HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
and in the console: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection] with root cause java.sql.SQLException: 
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Can anyone help me plz I cheched the connection with other java app it worked perfectly!

database.properties

```
 database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DAVDB
 database.user=root
 database.password=''
 hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
 hibernate.show_sql=true
 hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database.properties is not correct:

```
database.password=''
```

Should be:

```
database.password=
```

Assuming you want an empty password. Quotes have no special meaning in property files, so they will be taken as literal.

Comment: thank you for ur answer I changed it as u recommended but now getting  a new exception "Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection" Actually II m confused after a research there is recommendations to chech hibernate.cfg file But I don t have and I don t know even what it is !!

Comment: I haven't used Hibernate with Spring, so I'm not sure what the correct way would be. Maybe this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876147/integration-of-hibernate-with-spring-avoid-duplication-of-connection-parameters

Comment: hello I tested my code with a friend's pc it worked very well but I think the problem is with my database connection Aapache work as well as Mysql I don t know what's the problem with my pc  !! Any Help plzz

Comment: I think The error may be to difference in the ports Coz I ve changed the port of tomcat to 9000 I m wondering if the client is listenening to the same port How may I know so